# How to load page while send POST data in PHP

Tags: php

maybe this is sound's stupid but i want to make a page that can give some result when it is being called with a POST data..

lets say i have a.php with post data validation which can receive post data from outer server.

```
 if ((isset($_POST['authKey'])) && (isset($_POST['cmd'])) && ($_POST['authKey']==$this->key) && ($_POST['cmd']=='hello'))
        {
            if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $this->trusted))
               echo 'hello world';
        }
```

how to make b.php can get `hello world` by sending POST data.
Thank you..
Sorry my English is so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an HTML FORM on b.php

```
<form action="b.pbp" method="post">
  <input name="authKey">
  <input name="cmd">
  <button>Make request</button>
</form>
```

You can make an ajax request from b.php

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    alert(xhttp.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "b.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send('authKey=x&cmd=y');
```

You can make a cUrl request on the server side from b.php http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Using first way,i just get direct to a.php..i want to get that echo to my variable with a single request..is that posible?

Comment: Do you have a redirect from b.php to a.php? It's possible with ajax.